# Date formatting when pasting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

The bit of code below is just copying and pasting a date that will typically be in the form mm/dd/yy but could be anything.

```
WB1.Worksheets("WS1").Range(Cells(3, "g"), Cells(RowCountOPR, "g")).Copy
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack, "c").PasteSpecial
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack, "n").PasteSpecial
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack, "t").PasteSpecial
```

I would like it to paste in the format of yyyymmdd in the "c" column. How do I add that formatting here? Can I?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some lines that change the cell format's after:

```
WB1.Worksheets("WS1").Range(Cells(3, "g"), Cells(RowCountOPR, "g")).Copy
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack, "c").PasteSpecial
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack, "n").PasteSpecial
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack, "t").PasteSpecial 
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack, "c").NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
WB2.Worksheets("WS2").Cells(RowCountTrack + 1, "c").NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
```